# Importing interface from module with export = statement

Tags: typescript

Lots of type definition files make use of the `export =` directive, such as:

```
declare module "i40" {
    interface RouterStatic {
        () : Router;
    }

    interface RouteInfo {
        params : {
            [key : string] : any;
        };
        splats : string[];
        route : string;
        fn : Function;
        next : any;
    }

    interface Router {
        addRoute(routeString : string, action ?: Function);
        match(test : string) :RouteInfo;
    }

    export = null as RouterStatic;
}
```

Alternatively, someone might've written code like:

```
export interface Blah {}
const x = {hi : 5};
export = x;
```

EDIT: This code used to work once, but as of the current version (2.6), it won't compile. The compiler says that I can't use `export =` if I export other stuff from the module. Which makes sense.

How do I import one of the interfaces in the module? None of the following works.

```
import Router = require('i40');
let x : Router.RouteInfo; //RouteInfo not found

import {RouteInfo} from 'i40'; //RouteInfo not found

import * as Router2 from 'i40'; //Error, i40 is not a module
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say (Ref [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) under `Ambient Modules`)

```js
declare module "i40" {
  interface RouterStatic {
    ...
  }

  interface RouteInfo {
    ...
  }

  interface Router {
    ...
  }

  export { RouterStatic, RouteInfo, Router } as RouterStatic;
}

import * as Router2 from 'i40';
// use as Router2.RouterStatic,  etc

// or  
import { RouterStatic, RouteInfo, Router } from 'i40';
// use as RouterStatic,  etc
```

Comment: This will only work if I can modify the definition files, or else copy and paste stuff from them. Is there any other way?

Comment: Looks like the module may be declared incorrectly in the first place. `import * as Router2 from 'i40';` will give you whatever the source is exporting, but since  `//Error, i40 is not a module`, indicates a bad definition to me.

Comment: Any info on where the module is defined? Is it from a library?

Comment: The type definitions are from a library, yeah. You can check they work in your IDE. TypeScript allows those type definitions, but won't let you import stuff from them. Apparently it doesn't allow this kind of thing in proper TypeScript files (though I remember it used to).